# How to keep params as original values when performing an update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure if this is possible but thought I'll ask anyway.

I have a stored procedure where it will perform an update on a table. This stored procedure has five parameters:

```
@ClawbackID         int,
@PaymentID          int,
@ClawbackDate       date,
@ClawbackPercent    money,
@ClawbackAmount     money
```

So when the user executes the procedure, they need to fill in the values for the 5 parameters.

Now lets say for this occasion I want to update only 2 of the parameters, it means I still have to enter in the same values for the 3 parameters I don't want to change and enter in two new values for the 2 parameters I want to change. This could lead to more chances of human error.

I was wondering if there is a way it can be set so that parameters I don't want to change, I just keep the parameter name and the ones I do want t ochange, I enter in their values?

Example below where I change 2 of the 5 parameters is:

```
exec procexample @ClawbackID, @PaymentID, '2017-03-06', @ClawbackPercent, 1540.00
```

So the three params keep their original value and the two values entered are changed.

However this will need to be dynamic as on another occasion I may want to update 4 values, then next occasion could be only 1 value etc.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would pass `NULL` as the value for those parameters which you do not want to cause a change, and then use logic inside the stored procedure:

```
UPDATE t SET
    t.ClawbackDate=COALESCE(@ClawbackDate, t.ClawbackDate)
FROM UpdatableTable t
WHERE <criteria>
```

You can optimize that further when you bypass the `UPDATE` altogether in case all parameters are `NULL`, and in the `WHERE` clause, so records only get updated when there is an actual change:

```
WHERE t.ClawBackDate!=COALESCE(@ClawbackDate, t.ClawBackDate) OR ...
```

Comment: If you pass NULL as a placeholder for a value not to change how would you handle the user wanting to actually use NULL as the value? Since this is a stored procedure this is not how I would do it. I would make the parameters optional.

Comment: how would that work? is there a way to distinguish between "parameter value NULL" and "parameter omitted"?
When the columns to update are nullable, and NULL is a value you need to set, work with a pair of parameters each: one for the nullable value, and one bit passed 0 to ignore and 1 to update.

Comment: Oh I think I see what the OP is trying to convey....they didn't do a good job explaining what they are actually trying to do. I think what you are explaining may actually be what they need.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but I wanted to clean this one up.  (see the comments in the code)

```
-- Create a Dummy Table/Record to Log Param -- This would be an Actual table
Declare @LogParam Table (Log_ID int IDENTITY(1,1),PrcName varchar(250),ExecDT DateTime ,UsrID int,ParamXML XML);
Insert Into @LogParam Values (OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID),GetUTCDate(),1,'<ClawbackID>25</ClawbackID><PaymentID>5</PaymentID><ClawbackDate>2016-09-01</ClawbackDate><ClawbackPercent>0.5000</ClawbackPercent><ClawbackAmount>50000.0000</ClawbackAmount>');

-- In Your Stored Proc Collect Parameters (Let's assume only the ClawbackAmout was passed)
Declare @UsrID int = 1,@ClawbackID int,@PaymentID int,@ClawbackDate date,@ClawbackPercent money,@ClawbackAmount money = 25000

-- Collect and Set Values
Select @ClawbackID      = IsNull(@ClawbackID     ,ParamXML.value('(ClawbackID)[1]'     ,'int'))
      ,@PaymentID       = IsNull(@PaymentID      ,ParamXML.value('(PaymentID)[1]'      ,'int'))
      ,@ClawbackDate    = IsNull(@ClawbackDate   ,ParamXML.value('(ClawbackDate)[1]'   ,'date'))
      ,@ClawbackPercent = IsNull(@ClawbackPercent,ParamXML.value('(ClawbackPercent)[1]','money'))
      ,@ClawbackAmount  = IsNull(@ClawbackAmount ,ParamXML.value('(ClawbackAmount)[1]' ,'money'))
 From  @LogParam 
 Where UsrID = @UsrID
   and IsNull(PrcName,'') = IsNull(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID),'')
 Order By Log_ID Desc

-- Log Latest Parameters
Insert Into @LogParam values (OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID),GetUTCDate(),@UsrID,(Select ClawbackID = @ClawbackID,PaymentID = @PaymentID,ClawbackDate = @ClawbackDate,ClawbackPercent = @ClawbackPercent,ClawbackAmount  = @ClawbackAmount  For XML Path('')))


-- Just to Illustrate Current Log and Current Parameters
Select * from @LogParam
Select @ClawbackID
      ,@PaymentID 
      ,@ClawbackDate 
      ,@ClawbackPercent
      ,@ClawbackAmount
```

Results

[image]

The PrcName is NULL, but that would be calling Procedure Name

You may also notice the cost of of the Collection and Save was only 3 ms.